# React multiple Exports vs one Export

Tags: reactjs, webpack, tree-shaking

I was just having a discussion with a colleague about exports. I had a file with a provider component that also initializes a context. My code looked like this:

```
export const context = createContext(false)
export default function Provider({children}) {
       .....
}
```

His suggestion was to write it like this:

```
const context = createContext(false)
function Provider({children}) {
   .....
}
export {context, Provider}
```

The question is whether the different approaches have implications for treeshaking or are there other arguments for either method.